# Error al Crear un exe con pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

Mi codigo cuando lo ejecuto desde VS Code se ejecuta correctamente y funciona a la perfeccion pero al generar el .exe cuando se inicia el boton que activa la llamada a la libreria snap7 para hacer la comunicacion me devuelve este error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_ctypes.py", line 77, in __init__
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 376, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 no es una aplicación Win32 válida

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pytoexe.py", line 39, in <lambda>
  File "pytoexe.py", line 49, in leds
  File "snap7\client\__init__.py", line 64, in __init__
  File "snap7\common.py", line 72, in load_library
  File "snap7\common.py", line 64, in __init__
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 454, in LoadLibrary
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_ctypes.py", line 79, in __init__
pyimod03_ctypes.install.<locals>.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\snap7.dll'. Most likely this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
```

Cualquier info puede ser de utilidad

Comment: Según [este issue](https://github.com/gijzelaerr/python-snap7/issues/411), puedes intentar usar el [binario precompilado](https://pypi.org/project/python-snap7/#files) del módulo. Desinstala snap7, luego `pip install wheel` y luego intenta reinstalar **snap7**, revisando que lo esté haciendo desde el binario .whl y no de la fuente tar.gz. Acá hay otro [problema similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60822141/1545868), pero con otro módulo.